# How to register wso2 datasource defined in custom-datasource.xml in jndi

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am using WSO2 Data Services Server (v3.0.1) and I was wondering if it is possible to register a specific datasource defined in custom-datasources.xml in JNDI automatically (without using the console mgmt).

I tried to achived that with this configuration:

```
    <datasource>
        <name>IPL_DS_IDB</name>
        <description>My custom datasource</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>IPL_DS_DB</name>
            <environment>
                <property name="jndi.use.data.source.factory">true</property>
                <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory</property>
                <property name="java.naming.provider.url">rmi://localhost:10002</property>
            </environment>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/idb</url>
                <username>wso2user_idb</username>
                <password>XXXXXXX</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

But when I started the Data Services Server with this configuration, I have this exception:

```
TID: [0] [DSS] [2013-07-17 12:00:27,671] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository} -  Error in registering data source: IPL_DS_IDB - RegistryContext: object to bind must be Remote, Reference, or Referenceable {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RegistryContext: object to bind must be Remote, Reference, or Referenceable
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.encodeObject(RegistryContext.java:439)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:157)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:164)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContext.rebind(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:1046)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository.registerJNDI(DataSourceRepository.java:260)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository.registerDataSource(DataSourceRepository.java:360)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository.addDataSource(DataSourceRepository.java:474)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceManager.initSystemDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:182)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceManager.initSystemDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.internal.DataSourceServiceComponent.initSystemDataSources(DataSourceServiceComponent.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.internal.DataSourceServiceComponent.setSecretCallbackHandlerService(DataSourceServiceComponent.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
```

Someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **useDataSourceFactory** should be set as an attribute of **jndiConfig** element. So your datasource configuration should shange as follows.

```
<datasource>
        <name>IPL_DS_IDB</name>
        <description>My custom datasource</description>
        <jndiConfig useDataSourceFactory="true">
            <name>IPL_DS_DB</name>
            <environment>
                <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory</property>
                <property name="java.naming.provider.url">rmi://localhost:10002</property>
            </environment>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/idb</url>
                <username>wso2user_idb</username>
                <password>XXXXXXX</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```